# Collapse other buttons for nav menu in angular2

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am trying to create a multi-level navigation menu that collapses as you make your selections.

So if we have a tree of components... Module 1, Module 2, and Module 3 ... each with it's own sub-components (a, b, and c for each module) etc, etc.

When starting, I would like to be presented with options:

> Module 1 : Module 2 : Module 3

If the user selects Module 2, I'd like the following to happen:
1) module 1 and module 3 buttons collapse/hide 
2) the Module 2 button receives a 'down arrow' and effectively becomes a drop down consisting of Module 1, Module 2, and Module 3.
3) Nav buttons for Module 2 (2A, 2B, and 2C.. for example) show up.

So the result would look like this:

> **Module 2▼** > 2A : 2B : 2C

Further, then selecting 2C would do the same concept... collapse down 2A and 2B into a drop down on 2C and the nav option for 2C show up.  Leaving nice little breadcrumbs. The content for each item would show up below this menu.  This is not entirely unlike the navigation bar in modern file explorers (Say, Windows 10 File Explorer).

That said, I'm not entirely sure how to accomplish this.  I've started by cobbling together the various components into a tree navigation structure that works.  But when it comes to the collapsing, while I can make it kind of work, I can't help but think I'm doing it entirely wrong.  I don't want to go too far down this path only to find I've taken off in the wrong direction.

Here is the main app.component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `<h1>Multi level tree routing Proof of Concept</h1>
            App Navigate:<nav>
            <div *ngIf="navModShow[0]" >
                <a (click)="hideOthers(0);" [routerLink]="['/module1']">Module1</a>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="navModShow[1]" >
                <a (click)="hideOthers(1);" [routerLink]="['/module2']">Module2</a>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="navModShow[2]" >
                <a (click)="hideOthers(3);" [routerLink]="['/module3']">Module3</a>
            </div>
    </nav>
            <br>----------------App component router outlet below --------------<br>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
        })
export class AppComponent  {
navModShow = [true,true,true];  // TODO: has to be a better way?

    hideOthers(i) {
        this.navModShow.forEach( (item,index)=> {
            if(index!=i) {
                this.navModShow[index]=false;
            }
        });
    }
```